# Splunk-client (with Nokogiri) giving Undefined Namespace Prefix

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, splunk

I'm using splunk-client to extract results from splunk. Here's the code:

```
query = "sourcetype=collection #{order_id}"
search = @splunk_client.search(query)
search.wait
```

The search is happening fine, and it seems like I'm doing everything according to the example (https://github.com/cbrito/splunk-client), but I get this error on the 'search.wait' line:

```
Undefined namespace prefix: //s:key[@name='isDone']
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong? Running these commands in irb works fine. Is there some sort of blocking issue?

Comment: What version of Splunk? And did you try contacting the author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue -- the splunk client wasn't authenticating properly, and so `search` was actually a broken SplunkJob object (with a nil username and authentication key). It's strange that there was no error raised until the `wait` command, but upon inspecting the `search` object, one of the fields stated that the object was malformed.

Comment: There was a typo in the username during the authentication steps in rails.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently very little error checking which occurs within the gem itself. The reason for the error is that `wait` looks for the status of the `isDone` key to change to true.

Since your credentials were not properly setup in the first place, the gem creates a search object with an invalid session. The search does not initially fail, because enough response came back from Splunk that Nokogiri processes it into an object without a Splunk search sid.

In the future I should likely raise an exception if a proper sid is not returned to avoid confusion.

Source: I wrote the gem.